# Java - Search keywords list in another string list

Tags: java, algorithm, list, loops

I have a list of keywords in a List and I have data coming from some source which will be a list too.

I would like to find if any of keywords exists in the data list, if yes add those keywords to another target list.

E.g.

Keywords list = `FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME, CURRENCY & FUND`

Data list = `HUSBANDFIRSTNAME, HUSBANDLASTNAME, WIFEFIRSTNAME, SOURCECURRENCY & CURRENCYRATE.`

From above example, I would like to make a target list with keywords `FIRSTNAME, LASTNAME & CURRENCY`, however `FUND` should not come as it doesn't exists in the data list.

I have a solution below that works by using two for loops (one inside another) and check with String contains method, but I would like to avoid two loops, especially one inside another.

```
  for (int i=0; i<dataList.size();i++) {
      for (int j=0; j<keywordsList.size();j++) {
            if (dataList.get(i).contains(keywordsList.get(j))) {
                  targetSet.add(keywordsList.get(j));
                  break;
            }
      }
    }
```

Is there any other alternate solution for my problem?

Comment: How about a `Document Listener` which will extract the `JList data` depending upon the `String` matching. And with a few events, you could achieve what you want. I guess it is less complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a one loop approach using `regex`.  You construct a pattern using your keywords, and then iterate through your `dataList` and see if you can find a match.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    List<String> keywords = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("FIRSTNAME", "LASTNAME", "CURRENCY", "FUND"));
    List<String> dataList = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("HUSBANDFIRSTNAME", "HUSBANDLASTNAME", "WIFEFIRSTNAME", "SOURCECURRENCY", "CURRENCYRATE"));
    Set<String> targetSet = new HashSet();

    String pattern = String.join("|", keywords);
    for (String data : dataList) {
        Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(data);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            targetSet.add(matcher.group());
        }
    }

    System.out.println(targetSet);
}
```

Results:

```
[CURRENCY, LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME]
```

Comment: Thanks Shar1er80. I will probably go ahead with this idea as it looks good and gives me the output that I need, however just little bit concerned, that regex may not take extra processing time?

Answer (score 1):

Try Aho–Corasick algorithm. This algorithm can get the count of appearance of every keyword in the data (You just need whether it appeared or not).

The Complexity is `O(Sum(Length(Keyword)) + Length(Data) + Count(number of match))`.

Here is the [wiki-page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_algorithm):

> In computer science, the Aho–Corasick algorithm is a string searching
>   algorithm invented by Alfred V. Aho and Margaret J. Corasick. It is
>   a kind of dictionary-matching algorithm that locates elements of a
>   finite set of strings (the "dictionary") within an input text. It
>   matches all patterns simultaneously. The complexity of the algorithm
>   is linear in the length of the patterns plus the length of the
>   searched text plus the number of output matches.

I implemented it(about 200 lines) years ago for similar case, and it works well.

If you just care keyword appeared or not, you can modify that algorithm for your case with a better complexity:

`O(Sum(Length(Keyword)) + Length(Data))`.

You can find implementation of that algorithm from internet everywhere but I think it's good for you to understand that algorithm and implement it by yourself.

---

EDIT:

I think you want to eliminate two-loops, so we need find all keywords in one loop. We call it `Set Match Problem` that a set of patterns(keywords) to match a text(data). You want to solve `Set Match Problem`, then you should choose `Aho–Corasick algorithm` which is particularly designed for that case. In that way, we will get one loop solution:

```
for (int i=0; i < dataList.size(); i++) {       
  targetSet.addAll(Ac.run(keywordsList));
}
```

You can find a implementation from [here](https://github.com/pdonald/aho-corasick).

Comment: Thanks Sayakiss. Appreciate your idea. I had a quick look at the algorithm, it may work for my problem, however frankly the solution will become complex for a simple problem. I mean, while the solution of two for loops works with less than 10 lines of code, implementing an algorithm would be require good amount of efforts. I was kind of expecting solution that would save processing time & can equally be implemented in shorter duration. :)

Comment: @vnkotak see my `EDIT` in answer.

Comment: Thanks Sayakiss. It does look fine.